# sympy solve error unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve a set of equations with sympy.
It seems that  `xv1, yv1, zv1 = v`
is unpacked correctly.
I do not see what list the error code refers to.

```
def vectPerpend(v):
    import sympy
    'find vector in x_y plane perpendicular to the given vector'
    xv2, yv2 = sympy.symbols ("xv2,yv2")
    xv1, yv1, zv1 = v

    return sympy.solve ([xv2 ** 2 + yv2 ** 2 == 1,
                         xv1 * xv2 + yv1 * yv2 == 0], [xv2, yv2], dict=True)

print (vectPerpend ([3, 5, 1]))
```

I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\inequalities.py", line 671, in reduce_inequalities
    symbols = (set(symbols) or gens) & gens
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'



`**UPDATE**: the problem was that equations were presented as enequalities.
Changing from xv2 ** 2 + yv2 ** 2 == 1 to xv2 ** 2 + yv2 ** 2 - 1
     and from xv1 * xv2 + yv1 * yv2 == 0 to xv1 * xv2 + yv1 * yv2   
fixed the error.`
```

Comment: From a quick glance, it looks like you’re asking sympy to build a dict with you list of symbols as a key, and you can’t use a list as a key (because they’re mutable, and changing the list would break the dict). But you can just use a tuple instead.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, answers should not be edited into a question. If you found an answer, great - post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The error is in the way you wrote down the system

```
[xv2 ** 2 + yv2 ** 2 == 1, xv1 * xv2 + yv1 * yv2 == 0],
```

Both expressions evaluate to False immediately. So you are asking SymPy to solve the system

```
[False, False]
```

which of course isn't intended, and leads to odd error messages.

Either use `Eq(xv2 ** 2 + yv2 ** 2, 1)` to express an equation, or (easier) replace `=` by `-` to create the difference of left and right sides. An expression passed to `solve` is understood to be equated to zero.

```
sympy.solve ([xv2 ** 2 + yv2 ** 2 - 1,
              xv1 * xv2 + yv1 * yv2], [xv2, yv2], dict=True)
```

returns

```
[{xv2: -5*sqrt(34)/34, yv2: 3*sqrt(34)/34},
 {xv2: 5*sqrt(34)/34, yv2: -3*sqrt(34)/34}]
```

Comment: Good catch! Though I have to admit that the error message is pretty misleading on this one..